# Calling unknown (by name) lua function from C++

Tags: c++, lua

Here is what I want to do:

1) There is a lua function defined by the user, which I dont know by name. Say it is:

```
function f(x) return 2*x; end
```

2) The user will then call a function (that is designed in step 3) from Lua say like:

```
a=foo(f,3) --expecting a=6
```

3) The C++ function for foo is:

```
int lua_foo(lua_State *L)
{
    int nargs = lua_gettop(L);
    if(nargs<2) throw "ERROR: At least two arguments i) Function ii) number must be supplied";


    int type = lua_type(L, 1);
    if(type!=LUA_TFUNCTION) throw "ERROR: First argument must be a function";

    double arg2=lua_tonumber(L,2);
    lua_pushnumber(L,arg2);

    lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0) ; //trying to call the function f

    double result=lua_tonumber(L,-1); //expecting the result to be 6
    lua_pushnumber(L,result);

    lua_pop(L,nargs);

    return 1;
}
```

In the C++ code, I know the first argument is a function and second argument is a number. I am trying to call the first argument (the function) with the second argument (the number) as its arg.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Compiler error? Runtime error?

Comment: None, the result is always 0 rather than being 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is designed as below:

```
/* avoid `lua_` (or `luaL_`) prefix for your own functions */
static int l_foo(lua_State *L)
{
    /* `lauxlib.h` contains a lot of useful helper functions, e.g. for
     * argument type checking: */
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TFUNCTION);
    luaL_checknumber(L, 2);
    /* discard any extra arguments to `foo`; ignoring extra arguments
     * is customary for Lua functions */
    lua_settop(L, 2);
    /* the `lua_settop()` above ensures that the two topmost elements
     * of the stack are the function `f` and its argument, so
     * everything is set for the `lua_call()` */
    lua_call(L, 1, 1);
    /* return the topmost value on the Lua stack (the result); all
     * other stack values are removed by Lua automatically (but in
     * this case the result is the only value on the stack as the
     * `lua_call()` popped the function and the argument, and pushed
     * one result) */
    return 1;
}
```

It works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

By [reading the `lua_call` manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_call) it's seems to me to be a simple stack order problem. The stack should contain, in order, the function to call followed by the arguments in order.

When you call `lua_pcall` the stack contains the function, the argument to `foo` *and* the argument to `foo` *again* that you push. So the stack on the call of `foo` was already correct, and all you have to do is call `lua_pcall` without any other stack pushing.

---

There also the problem that you push the result *before* you pop the arguments to `foo` from the stack, which will leave the function `f` on the stack and not your result. Pop the stack first *then* push the result.

Comment: I modified the code as follows: `int nargs = lua_gettop(L);
  

  int type = lua_type(L, 2);
  
  double arg2=lua_tonumber(L,1);

  lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0) ;

  double result=lua_tonumber(L,-1);

  lua_pop(L,nargs);
  lua_pushnumber(L,result);



  return 1;` So now the function is on top of the stack and it still does not work.

Comment: As told, check the manual.  It says the stack must be: first the function, then `n` args.  After `lua_pcall()`, the stack contains only the results, so you shouldn't call `lua_pop(L, nargs)`.